# How to consolidate build statuses from several Jenkins instances in different locations on one dashboard?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

We have several teams located around the world (US, UK, India) who are quite well geographically concentrated on projects. Each team has its own Jenkins server at the moment for building their projects. Lets say it is like this:

- JenkinsA (US) [Project A]
- JenkinsB (India) [Project B]
- JenkinsC (UK) [Project C]

The sites are connected by (necessarily) high latency VPNs. There is a desire by management  have an aggregated view of the status of all builds across all teams. However we cannot consolidate to a single build system in one location as the integration systems are geographically distributed.

1. Is there a prebuilt solution for aggregating the status of all builds from various Jenkins instances on one webpage/dash? Something which could consolidate the various RSS feeds into a single display?
2. Given our development organisation's structure, geography and network topology, would there be any benefit to promoting the US instance to a Master, with the UK and India instances demoted to slaves? This would give us an aggregated view, but would introduce the US office and the slow VPNs as a single points of failure for all sites? Plus it would potentially take ownership of the build instances away from the teams.

Comment: have you checked cacti , or even better , can you assign one of your developers to touch the build log at each location and push the status to the dashboard

Comment: A log wont be needed.  Jenkins has a RSS feed. Just work off that and pull all the info together and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly easy way to do it, is to build a simple HTML page which pulls the status from the various Jenkins instances using the Jenkins API. 
Here is some JavaScript code that might work for you:

[Jenkins status](https://github.com/AF83/jenkins-status)

Answer (score 1):

This Jenkins plugin might also be of interest.

[wiki Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin)

The plugin description:

> This plugin allows records from one Jenkins to be published on another Jenkins. The typical use case is for you to run builds within the firewall, then send the results to another Jenkins which is facing the outside world.

The only issue I've found so far is that you must make sure the jobs have different names between the Jenkins instances. If there already is a job on the "public" Jenkins with the same name as a job you're trying to publish from your "private" Jenkins then the public job might get overwritten and then it seems impossible to disconnects the jobs again.